# Apache Rewrite Rules

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I got the basic Apache configuration more or less figured out with the guidance of the Apache manual but the redirection rules are a bit to complicated for me at this time so I hope you can help me.

I want to achieve the following:

- Every incoming request over http should be redirected to use https.
- Every subnet except for the ones defined as a vhost (m.domain.tld and content.domain.tld) should redirect to domain.tld.
- I rather keep everything after the "/" but this isn't necessary.

For example:

- http:/domain.tld → https:/domain.tld
- http:/whatever.domain.tld → https:/domain.tld
- https:/whatever.domain.tld → https:/domain.tld
- http:/m.domain.tld → https:/m.domain.tld

I got the basics working with this very basic rule but it only works for request coming in over http so non-existing subnets coming in over https aren't reformatted.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    Redirect permanent / https://domain.tld/
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope you can help or point me in the direction of a clear guide (haven't fount one yet).

Comment: To start with: https is served from different port than http: 443 vs 80 (default common port numbers). Forcing HTTPS -- tons of such topics already available here -- just search. The same for subdomain names: search for "canonical domain name". There is no problem with giving you exact rules for your case .. but since this kind of question is asked pretty much every 2nd day or so you should have no issues finding answers here. Look for them and update your post with any specific problems u still may have.

Comment: Really sorry, I hate my self for being "one of those guys", who never read and always ask. The reason I asked was because after a few days of looking at sites like stackoverflow I can't get a real grip on the rules. But I'm experimenting as I type. I'm only a bit scared of making a copy-paste ruleset with an obvious (security) flaw. Is it allowed when I have a working ruleset to "put them up for review" here?

Comment: If it's going to be "please check this" or "what is wrong here" then NO. If it's "this is what needs to be done; here is the rules; this is works and this does not -- can somebody help" -- Yes as you clearly showing that you working on it and need a bit of help/push in right direction etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these mod_rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

# force HTTPS for m.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =m.example.com
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# only allow m.example.com & example.com -- everything else gets redirected to https://example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=m.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=example.com
RewriteRule .* https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# if still no HTTPS then force it (for any other subdomain)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# your other rewrite rules below
```

Keep in mind, that in order to be able to server something.example.com you need proper SSL certificate for that particular subdomain or wildcard SSL certificate that will cover ANY subdomain. It is important, as SSL part of HTTPS works way before mod_rewrite will have a chance to do anything (it only kicks in when secure connection is already properly established).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! SSL is already working with a wildcard certificate. I hope I configured the virtual host correctly but it all seams to work.
I put the first and last rules in the <VirtualHost _default_:80> which is now the only contents of that vhost. So all request get redirected to <VirtualHost _default_:443> which include the DocumentRoot, server certs, etc. and I added your two last rules so that request to strange subdomains on https also get reformatted.